# Update column based on multiple meta key and values in SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm trying to bulk update coupons in the database which don't have an amount set and which are the discount type 'smart coupons' and have a usage count of 0. I've added a where clause which targets the meta key and values however when running it i'm getting 0 results returned. Can anyone help?

```
     UPDATE wpaf_postmeta 
        SET meta_value = 25
        WHERE meta_key = 'coupon_amount'
        AND meta_key = 'discount_type'
        AND meta_value = 'smart_coupon'
    AND meta_key = 'usage_count'
AND meta_value = 0
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: can you give us data for the above-mentioned filters?

Comment: I'm using Adminer

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress installations typically use MySQL.  And the key for the table is `post_id`.  Making these assumptions, you can do the filtering using `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE wpaf_postmeta p JOIN
       wpaf_postmeta pdt
       ON pdt.post_id = p.post_id AND
          pdt.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND
          pdt.meta_value = 'smart_coupon' JOIN
       wpaf_postmeta puc
       ON puc.post_id = p.post_id AND
          puc.meta_key = 'usage_count' AND
          puc.meta_value = '0'  -- Note the quotes.  meta_value is a string     
    SET p.meta_value = 25
    WHERE p.meta_key = 'coupon_amount';
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. However, I'm getting the error 'Error in query (1052): Column 'meta_value' in field list is ambiguous' when running testing this?